# I request ether from goerli faucet, it seem success, but eth.getbalance return 0

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, geth-debugging

**step1**: I launch the Geth ➜  `geth --datadir rinkeby --rinkeby --syncmode snap`

**step2**: I request ether from goerli faucet from the site: [https://fauceth.komputing.org/?address=0xe8fb264ce32e0160434b9987f8d0f99ed96e305d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Jnp.png), it seem successful because no error prompt.
[image]
**step3**: I interact with Geth `geth attach rinkeby/geth.ipc` , when I excute `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xe8fb264ce32e0160434b9987f8d0f99ed96e305d"), "ether")`, it returns 0. console prints log `ERROR[08-28|13:36:58.629] Expired request does not exist           peer=84e07faffaf52840f2f2791c50535b13983b131e0951b23782360076238ad54d`

***I expected to see balance transferred from faucet，Where did I go wrong？The problem also occurs in goerli ***

help pls.

Comment: Please consider to deploy own testnet on VM hosted by your own machine. Getting ether for existing testnets is painful process. Moving to own private testnet helps a lot to speed-up prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was frustrated with the same issue for my DApp. The deployment time and the faucet. Also investing hours on debugging.
I would suggest you to use BuildBear instead.
Try reading this https://medium.com/buildbear/win-web3-hackathons-using-buildbear-testnets-analytics-e67656093f9d
It will help you overcome the issue you’re facing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Pari Tomar, did you consider deploying private testnet on your own machine? I did this, but I also would like to know if you had a better experience with your solution if you had tried both.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure your balance is showing as 0, but if you need it, a Goerli faucet is https://goerlifaucet.com. It's by Alchemy so it's reliable.